# ROR paper_trial display all changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

Hi I'm pretty new to rails, and brand new to paper_trail.

I'm trying to display a simple table of all changes made from the versions table and display in a view

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Modified at</th>
    </tr>       
    <% PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc') do |v| %>
        <tr> 
            <td> <%= v.item_type.underscore.humanize %> </td>
            <td> <%= v.created_at.to_s %></td>
        </tr>       
    <% end %>       
</table>
```

unfortunately this renders the table headers but not the table body, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Open the rails terminal, type `PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc')` and show us the return...

Comment: ←[1m←[36mPaperTrail::Version Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "versions".* FROM "v
ersions" ORDER BY id desc←[0m
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PaperTrail::Version id: 4, item_type: "Lot", item
_id: 14, event: "update", whodunnit: "1", object: "---\nid: 14\nclient_id: 4\nco
mmercial: true\ncreated_at...", created_at: "2013-09-04 17:26:59">, #<PaperTrail
::Version id: 3, item_type: "Lot", item_id: 14, event: "create", whodunnit: "1",
 object: nil, created_at: "2013-09-04 17:25:33">, #<PaperTrail::Version id: 2, i
tem_type: "Lot", item_id: 4, event: "update", whodunnit: "1", object: "---\nid:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mising the `each` method call,

```
<% PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc').each do |v| %>
```